# Android design support navigation header mark item

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport

how can I mark an item (darker background) in the design support navigation drawer? I am setting the first fragment in the list (the on you first see when opening the app) in the `onCreate` option right after I initialize the navigation drawer like this: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, getMapFragment()).commit();`

Answer (score 0):

In your menu callback, make sure to call `menuItem.setChecked(true)`, ie:

```java
// From NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // TODO Do something with your menuItem
}
```

You can also do it in your menu XML with `android:checked="true"` on the appropriate menu.